# How to put HashMap into different elements with same key

Tags: java, spring, list, linked-list, hashmap

This is my output which contains three HashMap.

```
{2017-03-11=1, 2017-03-05=6}
{2017-03-11=1, 2017-03-05=5}
{2017-03-05=1}
```

i want them to look like this

```
date:2017-03-11
c=1, d=1, e=0

date:2017-03-05
c=6, d=5, e=1
```

Comment: what is `c`, `d`, `e`?

Comment: And I want to win the lottery. The difference being, that you can very easily get what you want, by simply **writing some code**.

Comment: So you have a list of HashMaps to begin with?

Comment: yes............

Answer (score 1):

You can make a wrapper class for the data structure such as

```
public class DateWrapper{
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int c;
    private Date date;

    public DateWrapper(int a, int b, int c, Date date){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.a = c;
        this.date = date;
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

and then just make a `Map<String, DateWrapper>`

this way of solving data structure of multiple things that are connected allows to manage setters, and add in more values easely

Comment: Let me try. :) 
But i already have three HashMaps and cant change them...

Comment: you can just get the data and insert it into the structure ( asuming you somehow know what is related to what)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may be looking for the [`MultiHashMap`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.2/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiHashMap.html) from the [Apache Commons Collections](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4)

Here's the example from the documentation:

```
MultiMap mhm = new MultiHashMap();
mhm.put(key, "A");
mhm.put(key, "B");
mhm.put(key, "C");
List list = (List) mhm.get(key);
```

Comment: No, I have tried that but no luck i could'nt done this the way i wanted the output

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more clear on what you want in that case.  Are you looking for a HashMap<HashMap<String>>?

Comment: I have three HashMap values and i need to extract them with one unique key and save them into variables. i have put expected output. I hope that might help you understand what i want...